# XSD 1.1 assert attribute must be present in document

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

Using XSD 1.1 is it possible to assert that an attribute exists somewhere else.

Example:

```xml
<root>
  <someelement>
    <lookup name="test"/>
    <bla>
      <lookup name="tbl2"/>
      <morebla>
        <evenmore>
          <lookup name="tbl2"/>
        </evenmore>
      </morebla>
    </bla>
  </someelement>
  <table name="test">
    ...
  </table>
  <table name="tbl2">
    ...
  </table>
</root>
```

How would I assert that the element lookup has a name that is used in an table element?

The assert would need to be on the root element since it's not possible to assert up the element tree, but how would I assert on every lookup element regardless of where it is in the document structure?

Comment: *//x* selects all nodes named *x*, as you can see in [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) of a simple tutorial.

Comment: Yes the //operator was what I tried myself. My idea was
every $i in 1 to count(//lookup)
satisfies exists(//table/@name = lookup[$i]/@name)
However that doesn't work, so I'm not sure if the //lookup part is wrong or my satisfies part.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've readed your question and I had thought that you didn't know that basic operator. You're approach is ok, take a look at my answer that also uses `every $v1 in $v2 satisfies` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in mind that in *XPath 2.0* comparing `$s1 = $sequence2` returns true if and only if `$s1` (or any of its elements if it is a sequence) exists in `$sequence2`. So you can use this simple *XPath* test for your assert:

```
every $lookupName in descendant-or-self::lookup/@name satisfies $lookupName = descendant-or-self::table/@name
```

Comment: Hm, I tried that, and executing that as an XPath 2.0 query it works, but as an assert in the xsd file it doesn't. I'm trying it with the Oxygen XML Editor 17.0 and it gives me the following error "System ID: /home/christian/BF-XML/test.xml
Main validation file: /home/christian/BF-XML/test.xml
Schema: /home/christian/BF-XML/test.xsd
Engine name: Saxon-EE 9.6.0.5
Severity: error
Description: Element root does not satisfy assertion every !$lookupName in //Lookup/@table satisfies $lookupName = //Table/@name
Start location: 21:0"

Comment: I tried a different validator and got a better error description:Engine name: Xerces
Severity: warning
Description: cvc-xpath.3.13.4.2b: An assert XPath expression such as ('every $lookupName in //Lookup/@table satisfies $lookupName = //Table/@name') containing / or //, on the schema type '#AnonType_root', cannot yield a valid result (since an assert tree is rooted at a parentless element).
Start location: 9:23
End location: 9:99
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cvc-xpath

Comment: @ChristianKruetzfeldt You're right (I was also using a query in Oxygen). In order to make it work in a XSD 1.1 assert, you can use axe *descendant-or-self*. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You might like to know that Saxon has an optimization for assertions of the form "every $x in ABC satisfies DEF" - if there's an element $x that doesn't satisfy the condition DEF, it will tell you about the location of that particular element.

Comment: @sergioFC Thanks, your updated answer works perfectly and even more important I also understand why - have learned something new about XSD.